# How does LastPass know that Microsoft.com uses the password for Live.com?

Tags: passwords, http, lastpass

When I visit Microsoft.com, the LastPass dropdown lists my username/password for login.live.com.  It does something similar for Playstation.com and several other sites.

How does it know?  Are these hard-coded into LastPass, or is there some markup or HTTP header or something on Live.com that specifies its credentials can be shared with other domains?

Comment: when you go to microsoft.com (as of Aug 31 2015) the "sign in" link at the top right takes you to a sign in page that has a URL beginning with "login.live.com" Is this what you see? if not please confirm that the URL of the sign in page is something other than login.live.com

Comment: This is a vendor-support question, not an InfoSec question.

Comment: @schroeder: Whether a question is "vendor support" or not shouldn't depend on the answer.  The answer here happens to be "they hard-coded it," but I had no way of knowing that without knowing the answer.  It could very easily have been an HTML or HTTP feature I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Either way, there is no InfoSec impact. If it was HTML or HTTP, then the question should be asked on another site, like SuperUser, or such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lastpass uses a preconfigured and extensible set of [site aliases](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=1256) to make two or more domains equivalent.

Here is a snapshot from my account settings page. YMMV.

[image]